# (Zero-knowledge?) Proof of Connection

Tags: cryptography, authentication, zero-knowledge-proofs

I have a conundrum to solve but am not knowledgeable enough about cryptography to know whether it's possible to do, and if so, what method to use.

I am a Provider and my task is to prove to some outside Verifier the existence of a Connection to some device, beyond some reasonable probability $\epsilon$. The Verifier and the Prover have a communication channel and can ask each other questions.
As a Prover, I could lie at any point, and pretend the Connection exists when it doesn't, or vice versa. I need a protocol that is secure in such a way that the Verifier can establish the Connection is genuinely there.

**Question 1**: Is there any such protocol that could do with with communication and computation on the Prover side alone?

**Question 2**: In case the former isn't possible, if the Device could do some computation (i.e. do (modular) arithmetic etc.) and the Connection could be used for that, would that make this possible?

[image: Diagram]

I feel there are some cryptographic algorithms out there that are designed for this, but I don't quite know what they are. I have looked into Zero-Knowledge proofs, but all the examples I find aren't quite suitable to this kind of issue.

Comment: Mh, can we take for granted that the device has encryption capability using a private key known of the Verifier only ?

Comment: What use could be the Prover pretending that there is no connection ?

Comment: We cannot take for granted that the Device has any private key known only to Verifier. If it had, I think that would make this all a whole lot easier of course, but let's imagine that the Verifier has no control over the hardware of the Device - though it may ask it questions.

There is no particular use in the Prover lying and pretending there is no connection. The main point/question I have is therefore how the Verifier can verify that the Prover is honest.

Comment: The answer will probably depend on what kind of connection, communication, or pre-established relationship the Verifier has with the Device; and on the capabilities of the Device.  Do you control the behavior and design of the Device?  If not, what is its behavior and design?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The Verifier must encrypt a message using the public encryption key of the device and ask the Prover to decrypt it. (Nobody knowing the private key.)

Comment: How would that work - would the Prover not be able to just pretend it was the device?

Comment: @Yellow: how could he decrypt?

Comment: The public key from the Device still needs to be communicated to the Verifier, via the Prover. So the prover just communicates its own public key, performs the task without talking to the device, and can then pretend the Device is there without it actually being there.

Comment: @Yellow: I assumed that the public key was... public.

Comment: If the Verifier knows nothing about the device, the dialog can only reduce to 

- hey, I have the device.
- maybe.

Comment: Well, that's exactly my question: is this possible? The answer may be "no"

Comment: @Yellow: seems obvious. If the Verifier has no a priori information on the Device, the Prover can always pretend to be the Device.

Comment: @Yellow: I have the Device, please ask me questions.

Comment: I'm happy for you that this is obvious to you. What would be more helpful as an answer would for example be the minimum type of (public or private) data for such a thing to be possible.

Comment: @Yellow: I said it: a public key.